# How to get the Contact_Id of the contact as soon as it is added to the phonebook using syncadapter?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-syncadapter

I am using android sample sync-adapter example code to sync my application's contacts database  with the phone-book and I need to update my contacts database with the Contact_Id allotted to them as soon as they are inserted by the sync-adapter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the ContentResolver.insert operation, the id is embedded in the returned URI. You can get it this way:

```
Uri resultUri = ContentResolver.insert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
if (rawContactId != null) {
    String rawContactId = String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(resultUri);
}
```